# How to avoid extending NSArray and thinking in Java whilst making pretty code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, macos, ipad

I'm going to do two something that is considered bad style, but I have reasons, and I'm open to a Cocoa solution, I just don't know what it is.

I want an `NSArray` which is type safe to a `UIView`, and then an `NSArray` which is type safe to arrays of `UIView`s. A 2D array of `UIViews`.

I'd like this because I've implemented a custom double `UITableView` which has a nested horizontal table view within a vertical table view. I would use my custom `ViewsArray` and `Views2DArray` as the data structure which other programmers easily give content to my `DoubleTableView`. Is that an adequate reason to want to extend `NSArray`?

The problem I'm having is that I've overridden the functionality of the method:

`(NSArray *) initWithObjects:(id) firstObject ...` as:

`(ViewsArray *) initWithViews: (UIView *) firstView, ...`

but the return value of my method is an `NSArray`, which does not have the other methods included in my `ViewsArray`, which means unrecognized selected exceptions. I've solved this temporarily by making a `NSArray` property of `ViewsArray` which has my views in it, but this makes for ugly code when I want to feed my content to my `DoubleTableView`.

Ex:

`[[self.delegate content].arraysOfViews objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`

Instead of

`[[self.delegate content] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];`

I know it's a few letters, but I'm trying my best to write good code.

How can I return `self` in my `initWithViews` and have an `NSArray` with my added properties of `greatestHeight`, `totalWidth`, etc? (Casting?) Am I thinking about this wrong (with Java/typesafity ...)? What's the best solution for a data structure like this?

Edit:

To solve my problem in a way I deem "stylish", I did the following:

This is my header (Notice it's an NSObject):

```
@interface ViewsArray : NSObject

@property int greatestHeight;
@property int greatestWidth;
@property int totalWidth;

- (ViewsArray *) initWithViews: (UIView *) firstView, ...;
- (UIView *) getViewAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;
- (NSUInteger) viewCount;

@end
```

This is in my implementation:

```
@interface ViewsArray ()

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSArray *views;

@end
```

Which means I just manage a private NSArray. Allowing for pretty references.

What I learnt today: Read the damn documentation and embrace your language. I know this instance may not show that last one, but I'm closer ;)

Comment: Maybe you have done this already, but please look at Apple's documentation for `NSArray`. There are subclassing notes at the top of it that essentially recommend against this. Personally, I would create a custom object and implement properties and methods on that object that get at my new datastore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Easy solution;   **don't bother**.

In using and debugging Objective-C apps using the NSArray/NSDictionary APIs for 18 years, I think I have run across wrong-class-in-collection problems only a few times.  In all cases, it indicated an over-arching design issue, not a programmatic error.

Simply put, your app controls the contents of collections and, unless you stick the wrong thing in a collection, your collection will contain exactly what you expect.  In a well written application, the number of places that might add something to a collection should be exceedingly small, typically only one or two spots.

If you do feel the need to be defensive against this, then add an `NSAssert([... isKindOfClass:...])` at the one or two locations that add stuff to the array.   No need to add the same at the points of retrieval.

There is, however, a common false-positive failure mode that'll appear to be an incorrect type in a collection.   If you over-release an object and an object of some other class happens to be allocated at the same location, then you'll see failures of this mode.

Comment: Okay. I accept this. But I still find the wrapper idea attractive because of the convenience methods that it allows for. Is there a hard solution? Where could I read about it?

Comment: I just carefully read the documentation. I get it now. I get both what I ought to do if I want this, and why it is I should avoid this. Thanks<3